# C++ Program reports symbol(s) not found error

Tags: c++

Hi I have been writing (and learning) C++ and I write all my code correctly in the program (or so I think). I get this error:

```
 "rands(int)", referenced from:
      _main in ccgc4zY9.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My code is this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int rands(int n);
int hits[10];

int main ()  {
    int n;
    int i;
    int r;
    srand(time(NULL));

    cout<<"enter a number of trials to run"<<endl;
    cin>>n;

    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        r=rands(10);
        hits[r]++;
    }

    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout<<i<<":"<<hits[i]<<"<Accuracy";
        cout<<static_cast<double>(hits[i])/(n/10)<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int randns(int n) {
    return rand()%n;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check your function name spelling ;)

Comment: It means just what it says. You haven't linked any file that defines a symbol `rands`. Did you mean `randns`?

Comment: Your code would be easier to read if it were indented properly, and easier to copy-and-paste without the line numbers.  (If an error message refers to a line number, add a `// This is line 42` comment.)

Answer (score 7):

You have defined a function called randns(), but call a function called rands(). The linker is telling you rands() is undefined, which looks to be correct.